# Angular Interpolation

Tags: angularjs

I am following a simple interpolation example but could not able to execute it properly. Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="js/angular.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="email" ng-controller="EmailController">
    To: <input type="email" ng-model="to" /> <br>
    Comment: <textarea ng-model="emailBody"></textarea> <br>
     <pre>__previewText__</pre>
</div>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My app.js is :

```
emailApp= angular.module('email',['emailParser']);

emailApp.controller('EmailController',['$scope','EmailParser',function($scope,EmailParser){
    $scope.$watch('emailBody',function(body){
        if(body){
            $scope.previewText= EmailParser.parse(body,{
                to:$scope.to
            });
            console.log("body: " + $scope.previewText);
        }
    })
}]);

emailParser= angular.module('emailParser',[]);
emailParser.config(['$interpolateProvider',function($interpolateProvider){
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol="__";
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol="__";
}]);

emailParser.factory('EmailParser',['$interpolate',function($interpolate){
        return {
            parse: function(text,context){
                   var template= $interpolate(text);
                   return template(context);
            }
        };
}]);
```

Please advise.

Comment: *could not able to execute it properly*: that's quite a poor description. What is the code supposed to do, and what does it do instead?

Comment: It is not working. It is supposed to show the Email preview. When I write "__to__" it should display the email address filed into the text box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$interpolateProvider) says

> Methods
>
> startSymbol([value]);
>
> ...
>
> endSymbol([value]);

So, these are methods, not attributes. Your code should thus be

```
$interpolateProvider.startSymbol("__");
$interpolateProvider.endSymbol("__");
```

although I'm not sure it's a good idea to use the same sequence for end and for start.

Once this fix is done, your code works as expected (at least, as I expect it to work, since you didn't explain what your expectations were): type `foo@bar.com`in the `to` field, type `__to__`in the `comment` text area, and the preview will display `foo@bar.com`.

Working plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/om4ShlL29faYfdLXxIFV?p=preview